# how to make a grid view to be paged?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a view like image below that has a list of items to be shown as gridview.but I want it to have like 8 of them in each page and user can go next and previous page.could you help me how to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use `Wrap` instead of `GridView` and you can handle it and it can fill the pages according to the screen size.
if you are fetching datas from api and it has pagination you can manage to show list of Wrap in every pages by clicking Next or Previous.
if you had any question about my answer i'm here to make it clear.
Happy coding...
Moraghebe khodet bash ;)

Comment: kheili mamnoon azizi